# The invoice hash API body does not match the (calculated) Hash of the XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

My Zatca onboarding worked properly the last time I used it 2 months ago.I tested with XML complete the process and everything seems alright. But from yesterday I am trying to onboard with same code and same XML this is throwing this error to me. And not working at all

**{"validationResults":{"infoMessages":[],"warningMessages":[],"errorMessages":[{"type":"ERROR","code":"invalid-invoice-hash","category":"INVOICE_HASHING_ERRORS","message":"The invoice hash API body does not match the (calculated) Hash of the XML","status":"ERROR"},{"type":"ERROR","code":"XSD_ZATCA_INVALID","category":"XSD validation","message":"Schema validation failed; XML does not comply with UBL 2.1 standards in line with ZATCA specifications","status":"ERROR"}],"status":"ERROR"},"reportingStatus":null,"clearanceStatus":"NOT_CLEARED","qrSellertStatus":null,"qrBuyertStatus":null}**

Here is the XML I am using for simulation compliance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
<ext:ExtensionContent>
<sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2" xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
<sac:SignatureInformation>
<cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
<sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
<ds:Signature Id="signature" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>7R4920paLHdfDZgCqSB+zL4IGNGHZ+xRLXWWkYnKISg=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>YWY3MTQzZjQ5YjYxYmY2MzhlOTI1MzY3ZWYyNTdmODA3YjQwM2E5YmRhNzQyM2NhNjE2Mzc1MDlmZTMyZDE4MA==</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>rJS0dVKxI/U8M8PlR7zjRO2QMoMeTdbyxqNNMoXQPGrwM1JN6KPgBIZW66iGsojSYX2DdejE+iBwkc6pTmUw1A==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object>
<xades:QualifyingProperties Target="signature" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
<xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SigningTime>2024-01-21T02:32:02</xades:SigningTime>
<xades:SigningCertificate>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>NWFhZmZmNDdjZjFiNjJlNTM0ZDIzMmMzMzQ0OGMxZTNmZGZjZGJiNzI5MzE1MzIwNGUzYTg2NWIwNTliZmU5Mg==</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=eInvoicing</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>1706038639091</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
</xades:SignedProperties>
</xades:QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
</sac:SignatureInformation>
</sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions><cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>INV104</cbc:ID>
<cbc:UUID>cae7dfce-0dd7-488b-97f2-2504f79d3713</cbc:UUID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2024-01-21</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:IssueTime>02:32:02</cbc:IssueTime>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0100000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
<cbc:Note languageID="ar">ABC</cbc:Note>
<cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
<cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
<cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
<cac:Attachment>
<cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
</cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
<cac:Attachment>
<cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">AQxBbHRhZiBNaWF6ZWUCDzMxMDk5MTI1NjIwMDAwMwMTMjAyNC0wMS0yMVQwMjozMjowMgQGMjMwMC4wBQUzMDAuMAYsN1I0OTIwcGFMSGRmRFpnQ3FTQit6TDRJR05HSForeFJMWFdXa1luS0lTZz0HWHJKUzBkVkt4SS9VOE04UGxSN3pqUk8yUU1vTWVUZGJ5eHFOTk1vWFFQR3J3TTFKTjZLUGdCSVpXNjZpR3NvalNZWDJEZGVqRStpQndrYzZwVG1VdzFBPT0IODA2MBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKAyIAAvxCxWD69KxsNfu60KK66UTwTD1isBk8IDBsmXzSsnv5CUcwRQIhANjTFl31bg+grcl9EP7y/h9QrFAE7MqH1dFqJC9tjagqAiB9/nZZlm36mVjDomT2AtrdN+XiCd78HntngET6FpVcUg==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
</cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference><cac:Signature>
<cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
<cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
</cac:Signature><cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:Party>
<cac:PartyIdentification>
<cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">310991252200003</cbc:ID>
</cac:PartyIdentification>
<cac:PostalAddress>
<cbc:StreetName>noakhali</cbc:StreetName>
<cbc:AdditionalStreetName>noakhali</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
<cbc:BuildingNumber>1234</cbc:BuildingNumber>
<cbc:PlotIdentification>12344</cbc:PlotIdentification>
<cbc:CitySubdivisionName>dhaka</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
<cbc:CityName>dhaka</cbc:CityName>
<cbc:PostalZone>12234</cbc:PostalZone>
<cbc:CountrySubentity>noakhali</cbc:CountrySubentity>
<cac:Country>
<cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
</cac:Country>
</cac:PostalAddress>
<cac:PartyTaxScheme>
<cbc:CompanyID>310991236200003</cbc:CompanyID>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:PartyTaxScheme>
<cac:PartyLegalEntity>
<cbc:RegistrationName>Altaf Miazee</cbc:RegistrationName>
</cac:PartyLegalEntity>
</cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cac:Party>
<cac:PostalAddress>
<cbc:StreetName>dhaka</cbc:StreetName>
<cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Dhaka</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
<cbc:BuildingNumber>1234</cbc:BuildingNumber>
<cbc:PlotIdentification>1234</cbc:PlotIdentification>
<cbc:CitySubdivisionName>dhaka</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
<cbc:CityName>riyadh</cbc:CityName>
<cbc:PostalZone>12235</cbc:PostalZone>
<cbc:CountrySubentity>Dhaka</cbc:CountrySubentity>
<cac:Country>
<cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
</cac:Country>
</cac:PostalAddress>
<cac:PartyTaxScheme>
<cbc:CompanyID>309876543098333</cbc:CompanyID>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:PartyTaxScheme>
<cac:PartyLegalEntity>
<cbc:RegistrationName>James</cbc:RegistrationName>
</cac:PartyLegalEntity>
</cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cac:Delivery>
<cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2024-01-26</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
</cac:Delivery>
<cac:PaymentMeans>
<cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
</cac:PaymentMeans>
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
<cbc:AllowanceChargeReasonCode>CG</cbc:AllowanceChargeReasonCode>
<cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>Cleaning</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
<cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.0</cbc:Amount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Percent>15.0</cbc:Percent>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
<cbc:AllowanceChargeReasonCode>95</cbc:AllowanceChargeReasonCode>
<cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>Discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
<cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">0.0</cbc:Amount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID> 
<cbc:Percent>15.0</cbc:Percent>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.0</cbc:TaxAmount>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.0</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxSubtotal>
<cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.0</cbc:TaxableAmount>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.0</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cac:TaxCategory>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5305">S</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Percent>15.0</cbc:Percent>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="6" schemeID="UN/ECE 5153">VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.0</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.0</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
<cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">2300.0</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
<cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.0</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
<cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">0.0</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
<cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.0</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
<cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">2300.0</cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="PCE">2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.0</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:TaxTotal>
<cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">300.0</cbc:TaxAmount>
<cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">2300.0</cbc:RoundingAmount>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Name>new product</cbc:Name>
<cac:SellersItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
</cac:SellersItemIdentification>
<cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
<cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Percent>15.0</cbc:Percent>
<cac:TaxScheme>
<cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
</cac:TaxScheme>
</cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">1000.0</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="PCE">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Here is my hashing with python

```
 et = ET.parse('Final_invoice_as_XML.xml')
            # # find the UUID element
            uuid_element = et.find('.//cbc:UUID', namespaces={'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'})
            hash_value = et.find('.//ds:DigestValue', namespaces={'ds': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'})

            # # extract the text value of the UUID element
            uuid = uuid_element.text
            hash_value = hash_value.text
            final_XML_invoice = str(final_XML_invoice)
            final_XML_invoice = bytes(final_XML_invoice, 'utf-8')
            # Store the encoded invoice data in base64 format
            encoded_invoice = base64.b64encode(final_XML_invoice).decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share always your import, too. You should have to learn debug your code. Your posted ERROR message have nothing to to with the shared python snippet, what you shared. There must be some comparison of the hashes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import base64

et = ET.parse('final_XML_invoice.xml')
# # find the UUID element
uuid_element = et.find('.//cbc:UUID', namespaces={'cbc': 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2'})
hash_value = et.find('.//ds:DigestValue', namespaces={'ds': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'})

# # extract the text value of the UUID element
uuid = uuid_element.text
print(uuid)
hash_value = hash_value.text
final_XML_invoice = "final_XML_invoice"
final_XML_invoice = bytes(final_XML_invoice, 'utf-8')
# Store the encoded invoice data in base64 format
encoded_invoice = base64.b64encode(final_XML_invoice).decode()
print(encoded_invoice)
```

Output:

```
cae7dfce-0dd7-488b-97f2-2504f79d3713
ZmluYWxfWE1MX2ludm9pY2U=
```

Note: I don’t have the value of final_XML_invoice variable, therefore I changed it to string.

The referenced hash methode in the xml is outdated: https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#sha256.

Comment: Sorry for that, but the value for the final_XML_invoice variable value is the XML I provided here.

Comment: @HosenMDAltaf Please clarify your question., please.What do you mean the variable is the XML, the bytes, the amount of characters, the file size  ???